# Continuity of $f(t)=t^{x-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, exponentiation

In our material we have the statement that for a given $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x\geq 1$ the function $f(t):[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, where $f(t)=t^{x-1}$, is continuous (if we define $0^0:=1$).

Then a few lines later we assume $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in]0,1[$ and consider another function $g:]0,1[\to\mathbb{R}$ with $g(\alpha)=\alpha^x$. Here $]0,1[$ is defined as the open interval from $1$ to $0$. We compute the limit: $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to 0}g(\alpha)= \lim\limits_{\alpha\to 0}\alpha^x$. However, in this case we suddenly rewrite $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to 0}\alpha^x=\lim\limits_{\alpha\to 0}e^{x\ln(\alpha)}$ in order to check the limit.

Why did we not use the previous result that we already know that $f(t)=t^{x-1}$ is continous? With this we could have simply said: $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to 0}\alpha^x=(\lim\limits_{\alpha\to 0}\alpha)^x=0^x=0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are right : If $g_x(\alpha) = \alpha^x$, and similarly $f_{y}(t) = t^{y-1}$, then $g_x(\alpha) = f_{x+1}(\alpha)$, so $g$ is a special case of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that when you change domains you change the function. Since you now have a left side to approach zero from you must ensure it also converges to the same number, otherwise it would be discontinuous there. For example if we take a step function and restrict the domain to one of the steps it is constant, and therefore continuous on that domain however it is certainly not continuous everywhere being a step function. This means you can't use the previous result because it doesn't apply to the new function in the larger domain.

Comment: the domain of $g$ is a subset of the domain of $f$ so I don't understand why your mentioned issue should cause any problems?

Comment: @Philipp It's because left and right hand limits can be different. If you restrict your domain to the left side and it is continuous, then the right hand side and it's continuous, you can't conclude that it's continuous everywhere. Again, step functions shows this clearly.

Comment: I understand your example but I don't understand how it applies here. We have $]0,1[\subset [0,1]$ so if $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ it would also be continuous on $]0,1[$.

Comment: @Philipp I haven't seen $]0,1[$ used as a subset of $[0,1]$ before. I read $]0,1[$ as $\mathbb{R}$ with $(0,1)$ removed. The only points they share are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Ah ok sorry for the misleading notation, in our lecture we have defined $]0,1[$ as the *open* interval from $1$ to $0$. I will edit my question to make this clear.

Comment: @Philipp that would be bizarre given the standard notation is $(0,1)$. Perhaps they forgot to add the qualifier "compliment of" which would align with the notation I'm familiar with and justifies their proof. I would ask the lecturer to clarify.

Comment: No, it is not the complement. In this context $]0,1[$ is definetly the open intervall.

Comment: @Philipp Then as you said there isn't any reason to prove it. I think human error is by far the most likely explanation but if you insist that your lecturer is infallible who am I to argue?